# How does one query a database?

Tags: sql

How does one get the first name info from a Users table, which has a first name column?

Comment: See the [SELECT Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html). It might help to show what you've tried and where specifically you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

First of all welcome to the community. I suggest you read the guidelines on how to properly ask a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and you might want to write a title that is relevant to your question.

Now to the question:
Assuming tblUsers is a table in your database and 'first_name' is a column in your table, you can use **SELECT** followed by the column you want to select.
Lastly, add **FROM** to select which table you want to select from.
So in your case it would be:

```
 SELECT first_name FROM tblUsers;
```

You can read more about SELECT [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp)